# Set and pass environment variable from Fastlane to calling bash script

Tags: bash, fastlane

I am wanting to set an environment variable in Fastlane, and pass it back to a calling Bash script.

Just as a simple example, I run this Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

fastlane beta
echo $DELIVER_USER
```

Somewhere in my lane code I have:

```
sh(command: 'export DELIVER_USER=joe')
```

But the `echo` in the calling script does not show "joe", it doesn't show anything. Is there a way that I can do this? Or some other way to be able to pass a value from Fastlane back to the calling Bash script?

Comment: A parent process can *initialize* the environment of a child process, but it cannot seen any further changes to that environment made by the child. Similarly, there is no way for the child to modify the environment of its parent.

Comment: The usual way for a command to pass data out is for it to print the data to stdout, and for the calling script to capture it with something like `DELIVER_USER=$(fastlane beta)`. Note that this captures *everything* the command sends to stdout, so anything you don't want captured (e.g. status or error messages) should be sent to stderr instead (that's what it's for). If it needs to send more than one value, it needs to print the values in some form that the script can parse to separate out the values.

Comment: Write the value you want to pass to the parent process to a file, and read the file in the parent process. I suggest that the parent process passes the file name to your script via an environment variable, so that you avoid concurrency problems.